# bash script uses gcc in a loop to compile all

Tags: linux, bash, gcc

I need write bash script that uses gcc in a loop to compile all .c source files in current directory into .o object files, and additionally creates .s assembly listings in Intel format. Then, the .o files are linked into run executable.

```
    for i in *
do
    gcc -type -f "*.c"
done
```

i just began that but I'm not sure I began it correctly

Comment: I agree with @sannaj's answer. But what a strange question. Did you try executing your script? If so, you will know if you began it correctly or not.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/makefile/info

Answer (score 0):

Rather them writing a bash script, it's acutally better to write a makefile which is specialised in automatizing this kind of things.

Comment: @IsraelIsraeli No you don't

Comment: If you want to treat all the `.c` files the same way, you need a pattern rule https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html